# Does device token for my app changed when there is an update for my app in app store?

Tags: ios, devicetoken

I googled it and I can't seem to find an answer for that: does device token get changed when there is an update from app store for my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Device tokens can change.** Your app needs to reregister every time it
>   is launched — in iOS by calling the `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:`
>   method of `UIApplication`.

Source: [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW1)